# C# Use of Unassigned local variable - out statement

Tags: c#, out

I've looked for this problem but I don't know (and haven't found) how to solve it. Does anyone here know how to solve the problem? I'm using EMGU, but the issue is with the c# coding (I'm reasonably new to C#) - I think it's to do with the out statement as I haven't used them much:

```
Image<Gray, Byte> first_image;

if (start_at_frame_1 == true)
{
    Perform_custom_routine(imput_frame, out first_image);
}
else
{
     Perform_custom_routine(imput_frame, out second_image);
}

Comparison(first_image);
```

Comment: If `start_at_frame_1` was false, `first_image` hasn't been assigned a value for that call to `Comparison()`. That's what you're being warned about. How to fix it will depend on your desired behaviour. Also, `== true` is a redundant test - you could just have `if(start_at_frame_1)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must give default value to the variable:

```
Image<Gray, Byte> first_image = null;
```

Otherwise there is a chance you won't assign anything, if you pass `second_image` as the out parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options of doing it

```
Image<Gray, Byte> first_image = default(Image<Gray, Byte>);
```

or

```
Image<Gray, Byte> first_image = null;
```

or

```
Image<Gray, Byte> first_image = new Image<Gray, Byte>();
```

Don't forget to do this with `second_image` also.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth no, in the else block the out argument is `second_image` and not `first_image` so there is a scenario where it won't be reassigned.

Comment: @Hinek True, didn't spot that at first. However, in the case when `Perform_custom_routine(imput_frame, out first_image);` is called `first_image` is guaranteed to be re-assigned, so assigning `new Image` in this case would be pointless.

Comment: These are 3 of several options, not the only 3 options.  You could also ensure that it is assigned in the `else` block, or that all calls to `first_image` are moved to within the `if` block, just to name a few others.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is warning you, that you are about to use an unassigned variable in your call to `Comparison`. If `start_at_frame_1` is `false`, your variable `first_image` would never be set.

You can address this by setting `first_image = null` either in the initialization or in the else block.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could make it a return parameter from Perform_custom_routine.

```
Image<Gray, Byte> first_image;  

if (start_at_frame_1 == true)  
{  
    first_image = Perform_custom_routine(imput_frame, out first_image);  
}  
else  
{  
     first_image = Perform_custom_routine(imput_frame, out second_image);  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use the 'out' keyword, you have to give the variable a value before passing it.

If you use the 'ref' keyword, you have to give the variable a value in the method you pass it to before returning.

Comment: The out variable shouldn't have a value when you call the function... Unless I am reading your text completely wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure why the down vote here - a ref variable must be assigned before it is passed as a parameter, where as an Out does not need to be!